# How to make a 2D plot with color density as the 3rd argument in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to make a plot where each point it has its x&y value and it also has a third value (column z) expressing the color density at that point. I don't know how to show it in mathematica???
I would be really grateful if you help me about that.

kind regards

Comment: You're probably looking for `DensityPlot[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the colour density in PlotMarkers or PlotStyle.

```
ListPlot[Table[{{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}}, {n, 50}],
 PlotMarkers -> Array[
   Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[Mod[#/5, 1] + 0.2], Disk[]}, 
     ImageSize -> 10] &, 50]]
```

[image]